# is there any possible way to add GeoFence into Mapbox?

Tags: java, android, mapbox, android-geofence

I am not able to place GeoFence into Mapbox. Does anyone know how to add GeoFence into Mapbox or if any other solution for how to check that my current location is into route or not.

Comment: Are there any examples or documentation online? Have you tried this? What problem are you encountering specifically?

Comment: if you have any suggestion for this question or i make any mistake in the quesiton please mention into the comment section(for the down vote person)

Comment: No @halfer ,today someone downvote this question so that i wonder that after a long time someone is waked up.

Comment: yes you are right, let we will move ahead

Answer (score 1):

Geofencing will most likely be introduced when we upgrade our location service (LOST) to 2.0, you can track the [ticket here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/6537). If you are trying to detect when a user gets off route, you can use the latest [Mapbox Android Services](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/#mapbox_android_services) 1.3.1 which includes a `RouteUtils` class. When you construct the object you can pass in the distance tolerance (default is 50 meters) and then call `RouteUtils.isOffRoute()` inside a `onLocationChange` listener. Here's [an example](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/master/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/labs/OffRouteActivity.java) found in the demo app you can use to learn how to use.

You can also use `TurfJoins.inside()` inside the same SDK (Mapbox Android Services) which will check if the point in within a polygon or not. [Checkout this example](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-java/blob/master/libandroid/app/src/main/java/com/mapbox/services/android/testapp/turf/TurfInsideActivity.java) to see how to use it.

Comment: Any update on this now that LOST new version has been released and Mapbox integrated it would be welcome!

Comment: both example links are dead

Comment: Hi cammace - would you repair the example links please, or remove them?